# Launching Vue UI throws error: spawn cmd ENOENT

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cmd, vue-cli

When in cmd and I use the 'vue ui' command I get this error:

```
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://localhost:8000' ]
}
```

I've made sure node and vue are both up to date and have uninstalled/reinstalled both to be sure there wasn't something wrong there. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: Try deleting the `node_modules` folder and re-install with `npm i` then try running `vue ui` again

Comment: @Phil tried this, but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

You should add `C:\Windows\System32` folder to you environment variables

Comment: This was one of the first things I had tried, thank you though.